# Can anyone briefly explain what is Dhamma?

Tags: dhammas

Can anyone please explain what is Dhamma in few paragraphs if possible?

A similar question was asked by Rahula in Samyukta Nikaya but what I have is English translation of the conversation which leaves me with doubts. Also I want to establish meaning of Dhamma before asking few more questions based on it.

Comment: This question seems very broad because dhamma can mean many things.

Comment: In Samyukta Nikaya Buddha answers the question of Rahula thus put :"Then
the Venerable Rahula approached the Blessed One, paid homage
to him, sat down to one side, and said to him:
"Venerable sir, it would be good if the Blessed One would
teach me the Dhamma in brief, so that, having heard the
Dhamma from the Blessed One, I might dwell alone, withdrawn,
diligent, ardent, and resolute."" Then Buddha goes on to explain Dhamma.

Comment: @DheerajVerma Could you quote the exact sutta that you are referring to? Perhaps providing a link to it as well?

Comment: I have a book "A translation of Samyutta Nikaya by Bhikku Bodhi" in which on page 694 the above conversation between Rahula and Buddha is reported. Online it can be found [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=MEA6AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA694&lpg=PA694#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: In [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/22773/254) I summarized nearly all the suttas which [Dhammadhatu's comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/22605/can-anyone-briefly-explain-what-is-dhamma/22606#comment38056_22606) says are the handful of sufficient core suttas. And the other answers to that topic might interest you.

Answer (score 6):

The term dhamma has multiple meanings in Buddhism. Dhamma is defined in the accesstoinsight.org [glossary page](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/glossary.html#d) as:

> dhamma [Skt. dharma]:(1) Event; a phenomenon in and of itself; (2)
>   mental quality; (3) doctrine, teaching; (4) nibbāna. Also, principles
>   of behavior that human beings ought to follow so as to fit in with the
>   right natural order of things; qualities of mind they should develop
>   so as to realize the inherent quality of the mind in and of itself. By
>   extension, "Dhamma" (usu. capitalized) is used also to denote any
>   doctrine that teaches such things. Thus the Dhamma of the Buddha
>   denotes both his teachings and the direct experience of nibbāna, the
>   quality at which those teachings are aimed.

If you want to know more about Dhamma, the doctrine and teachings of the Buddha, see [this page](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/index.html).

If you want to know more about dhamma (mental quality or mental object), the fourth foundation of mindfulness, see [this page](https://www.budsas.org/ebud/ebmed063.htm), [this page](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/soma/wayof.html#mental) and the [Satipatthana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.010.than.html#mental).

Comment: I want to know Dhamma as understood by Buddha when he was asked "Could you please explain Dhamma in brief?"...

Answer (score 3):

In the [Rahula Samyutta](http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/3Samyutta-Nikaya/Samyutta2/17-Rahula-Samyutta/01-Pathamovaggo-e.html), the word 'Dhamma' refers the teachings of 'ultimate or higher truth' (*lokuttara dhamma*), which lead to developing the Noble Eightfold Path & enlightenment. As stated:

> *Venerable sir, it would be good if the Blessed One would teach me the Dhamma in brief, so that, having heard the Dhamma from the Blessed
>   One, I might **dwell alone, withdrawn, diligent, ardent and resolute**.*

In response, the Buddha teaches Rahula about impermanence, unsatisfactoriness & not-self, which is a teaching leading to Nibbana (rather than mere mundane teachings about kamma & 'rebirth', which are not 'Dhamma' with a capital 'D').

---

The Pali is: "*bhagavā saṃkhittena dhammaṃ desetu*"; if searched at:  https://suttacentral.net/, will probably find wherever this phrase is used, the outcome of the suttas found (see [link](https://suttacentral.net/search?query=bhagav%C4%81+sa%E1%B9%83khittena+dhamma%E1%B9%83+desetu)) is Nibbana or enlightenment. This shows the word 'Dhamma' in the contexts means 'higher truth' rather than 'phenomena' or 'mind object'.

This is the right or proper way to study Buddhism, namely, examining how a word is used in the context of the various suttas.

Using dictionaries & ordinary scholar explanations is the wrong way to study Buddhism, causing lifelong confusion. Dictionaries & commentators is 2,400 years of the blind leading the blind.

Comment: Buddha answers 3 characterizes of 6 āyanana to rāhala to go to dwell alone, withdrawn, diligent, ardent and resolute, so dhamma that asked by rāhula definitely is not lokuttara dhamma (4 magga 4 phala 1 nibbāna). He asking for an object of kammaṭṭhāna (6 āyanana).

Comment: Your comment is wrong. Anatta-Ayatana is lokuttara. Please stop commenting on my posts with unless Abhidhamma. MN 117 & SN 20.7 define what lokuttara dhamma is. The sutta to Rahula ends with a teaching about Nibbana. Thanks

Comment: It is end with nibbāna, but the end is not answer of sutta. The answer id before the end. And the topic owner ask for Dhamma word that buddha answered before the end of sutta. Reference of lokuttara: Suttanta K.N. Paṭi (by sāriputta-mahāsāvaka)-- katamo lokuttaro vimokkho? cattāro ca ariyamaggā, cattāri ca sāmaññaphalāni, nibbānañca – ayaṃ lokuttaro vimokkhoฯ (What is lokuttara-vimokkha? They are 4 ariya-magga, 4 phala, and nibbāna.)

Comment: I follow the Buddha (and not scholars who have never practised). Your comments are wrong. Your method of study leads only to blind faith & repeated recitation of magical words. It is like the Prophet Mohamed (PBUH) who wrapped himself in blankets and recited endless words. Regards

Comment: You lying everybody by using theravāda-tipitaka, but you never faith any theravāda-methods. I am a theravāda. I can claim to make the listener see the truth, that you try to hide from them. because I use theravāda-tipitaka without a bad faith to lie the listener by cutting tipitaka off. You trying to cutting off tipitaka, dhammadhātu. I see it in every post of you. **I always straightforward by tipitaka, commentary, sub-commentary, bh. pa-auk word by word.** So I just make people see your lying by making them see the truth that appear in tipitaka. I'm sorry, for your vippaṭisara.

Comment: theravāda-tipitaka is rubbish. only Buddha-Vaca is dhamma.

Comment: So you why don't you avoid theravāda tipitaka anymore, even just a part of it, to avoid the rubbish?

Comment: To take refuge in Tripitaka is to dishonor the Buddha because the Buddha said his dhamma is perfectly spoken (Svakkhato Bhagavata dhammo). Taking refuge in Tripitaka means believing the core sutta is imperfectly spoken; believing Buddha was not a perfect teacher. Core sutta is good. Some sutta is rubbish, later addition. Abdhidhamma is unnecessary. Only a handful of core sutta is enough for enlightenment. MN 117; SN 56.11; SN 22.59; SN 22.79; SN 23.2; SN 5.10; MN 9; MN 61; DN 31; SN 55.7; AN 4.55; MN 118; MN 38; MN 37; Iti 44; Iti 49; MN 149; SN 22.53; MN 115; SN 22.81; SN 22.48 is enough.

Comment: Dhamma has many meanings in context. "Teachings" is too broad for me. By "his or Buddha's teachings", it is mean "lokuttara teachings", the same as my answer. Regards

Comment: I used your list of suttas to create [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/22773/254).

Answer (score 2):

Dhamma is truth. Dhamma is wisdom. Dhamma is the path to liberation of suffering. Dhamma is the teaching about truth to attain wisdom.

Comment: What is the Truth ?

Comment: I would need to talk for innumerable amount of years to tell you what is the Truth. You would not realize it because of the wisdom I communicated to you, but because of you being bored of me communicating it to you. What I'm telling you is that nobody can tell you what is the Truth, but you. Only by yourself you can realize the Truth. I cannot realize it for you. I can guide you towards realization of the Truth, but cannot tell you what it is, because realization of what the Truth is depends solely on you.

Answer (score 0):

The [saṃyuttanikāya cakkhusutta](http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/3Samyutta-Nikaya/Samyutta2/17-Rahula-Samyutta/01-Pathamovaggo-e.html) that was **quoted by the topic owner**, already answered by buddha.

Rāhula asked for an **object (dhamma)** for contemplating (insight meditation), so buddha answered 6 āyatana (dhamma) that have 3 characterizes (dhamma's property) for contemplating, to him.

> 17. 1. 1.
>
> (1) **Cakkhu** - The Eye
>
> 1. I heard thus. At one time the Blessed One was living in the monastery offered by Anāthapiṇḍika in Jeta's grove in Sāvatthi.
> 2. Then venerable Rāhula approached the Blessed One worshipped and sat on a side.
> 3. Sitting on a side venerable Rāhula said to the Blessed One: “Venerable sir, Blessed One, may I be taught **(dhamma)** so that I would withdraw
>      and seclude and abide diligent and zealous to dispel.”
> 4. “Rāhula, is the **eye (dhamma)** permanent or impermanent?”
>
> “It's impermanent, venerable sir.”
>
> “That which is impermanent is it unpleasant or pleasant?”
>
> “It's unpleasant, venerable sir.”
>
> “That which is impermanent, unpleasant, a changing thing is it
>   suitable to be considered `that is mine, I am that, it's my self?'”
>
> “That is not so, venerable sir.”
>
> 5. “Rāhula, is the ear ... re ...
> 6. ... re ... nose ... re ...
> 7. ... re ... tongue ... re ...
> 8. ... re ... the body ... re ...
> 9. ... re ... the mind permanent or impermanent?”
>
> “It's impermanent, venerable sir.”
>
> “That which is impermanent is it unpleasant or pleasant?”
>
> “It's unpleasant, venerable sir.”
>
> “That which is impermanent, unpleasant, a changing thing is it
>   suitable to be considered `that is mine, I am that, it's my self?'”
>
> “That is not so, venerable sir.”
>
> 10. “Rāhula, the noble disciple seeing it thus turns away from the eye, turns away from the ear, turns away from the nose, turns away
>       from the tongue, turns away from the body and turns away from the
>       mind.
> 11. “Turning away detaches himself, is dispassionate and is released. Released, knowledge arises, `Birth is destroyed, the holy life is
>       lived, duties are done, there is nothing more to wish'.”

Comment: Yes. That is correct but I was looking for a summary. Something like "Sabbe sankhara anicca"
"Sabbe sankhara dukkha"
"Sabbe sankhara anatta"

Comment: It is "Sabbe Dhamma Anatta" not "Sabbe sankhara anatta"

Comment: Summāry are truth: 121 consciousnesses, 52 mind objects, 28 matters, and 1 nibbāna.  And summary also is imagination: paññtti. This is called abhiññeyyadhamma in sutta. See paṭisambhidāmagga, abhidhamma, and learn pāli for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know what Dhamma is in briefly, well Dhamma is everything that prince siddhartha understood by himself when he became the lord buddha. Dhamma is everything lord buddha taught to his followers. in very briefly Dhamma is what we learning and following today as Buddhists.

Answer (score 0):

As if you want to know same as Buddha explained to Rahula it is, nothing is eternal. Everything has to cease and that he trying to get from Rahula if he understand suffering at all. And what we desire with sensation of **eye**, **ear**, **nose**, **tongue**, **body**, and **mind** that we have to overcome sensuality with these sixth strings of sensuality and further things he explained are **Form**, **Consciousness**, **Contact**, **Feeling**, **Perception**, **Volition**, **Craving**, **Elements**, and **Aggregates**. Buddha explaining Rahula that all Forms, Consciousness, Contact, Feeling, Perception, Volition, Craving, Elements we get sense with sixth strings of sensuality and those aren't permanent. He explained with **Element** that after we die body and soul merge in the earth Elements and that elements also aren't eternal. And eventually aggregates that everything **Form**, **Consciousness**, **Contact**, **Feeling**, **Perception**, **Volition**, **Craving**, **Elements** (That we could get sense with sixth strings of sensuality are ***eye, ear, nose, tongue, body and mind***) are Impermanent.

> **Forms :** *sounds, odors, tastes, tactile objects, mental phenomena*      forms we get through sixth sense.
>
> **Consciousness:**  ***eye**-consciousness, **ear**-consciousness, **nose**-consciousness , **tongue**-consciousness, **body**-consciousness and **mind**-consciousness*.
>
> **Contact:** ***eye**-contact, **ear**-contact, **nose**-contact, **tongue**-contact, **body**-contact and
>
>   **mind**-contact.*
>
> **Feeling:**  *feeling born of **eye-contact**, feeling born of **ear-contact**, feeling born of **nose-contact**, feeling born of **tongue-contact**, feeling born of **body-contact** and feeling born of **mind-contact***.
>
> **Perception:**  *perception of **sound**, perception of **odors**, perception of **tastes**, perception of **tactile objects**, **perception of mental phenomena***.
>
> **Volition:**   *volition regarding **form**, volition regarding **sound**, volition regarding **odors**, volition regarding **tastes**, volition regarding **tactile objects**, volition regarding **mental phenomena***.
>
> **Craving:**  *craving for **form**, craving for **sound**, craving for **odors**, craving for **tastes**, craving for **tactile objects**, craving for **mental phenomena***.
>
> **Elements:**  *The water element, The heat element, The air element, The space element, The **conscious** element*
>
> **Aggregates:**  ***form**, **feeling**, **perception**, **volitional** formation, **consciousness***

So see the beginning and the end. I'd say telescopic like if we have to sensuality with sixth strings of sensation we experience(*impermanent*) everything as Buddha explained so Rahula experiences revulsion towards forms, 
revulsion towards consciousness.
Experiencing revulsion, he becomes dispassionate. He understands.
So we have to free from this all and have to achieve peace and *Nirvana*.
This is **Dhamma**

Answer (score 0):

The **Dhamma** is a way of training that prompts intelligence and freedom from torment. One's comprehension of **Dhamma** turns out to be ever more profound and significant as one advances along the way, old exercises uncovering new certainties as one creates further knowledge and comprehension of Dhamma; "Similarly as the sea has a slow retire, a continuous slant, a steady tendency, with a sudden drop-off simply after an extended length, similarly this Doctrine and Discipline **(Dhamma-Vinaya)** has a slow preparing, a continuous execution, a slow movement, with an entrance to gnosis simply after an extended length". The fundamental significance of rehearsing Dhamma is to Mindfully hone contemplation, learn and show Dhamma as one has comprehended it, and consolidate it with the ethical standards of Sila , and to utilize these devices to live as indicated by the standards of the Noble Eightfold Path.